# WooCommerce update_status() is causing infinite loop in hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, infinite-loop

I'm trying to update order status when a Store Manager clicks 'Completed'.

I'm doing this because I want to check something (if a 'key' is present) on 'Completed'. If the condition is not met, then I want to set the order back to 'Processing'

The problem: using the hook 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' I get an infinite loop.

Here is the function simplified. This triggers the issue. Any thoughts why I'm getting a runaway loop?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'xcsn_woocommerce_order_status_completed' );
function xcsn_woocommerce_order_status_completed ( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $order->update_status( 'processing', 'Set to Processing because Keys were not available' );

    // Surely the above means the hook 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' should only be triggered once?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to change status order to processing if it meets a condition.
With the current function, change order processing to complete and completed to processing because there is no condition that prevents it.
I think you should try
`if ($ Order-> order_date current_date == () + $ delay_days) {
   // Do stuff 
}`